# ArcMap conditional statement raster attribute?

Tags: classification, arcgis, envi

I'm having difficulty with the syntax to do the following:

I have four raster products from various classifications. Each has one or two classes representing the units I am interested in, so I want to use raster calculator to make a new raster where unit of interest in each of the inputs is reduced to values of 0 or 1 (for presence or absence of class(es) of interest) and then summed into a final raster values 0 to 4 to represent degree of agreement between classification methods.

When inspecting these rasters they have attributes "Class Name", "Color Index" and "Color(a,r,g,b)", and I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax to query them.

Thank you!

RT

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem. I was "viewing" classification rasters in ArcMap after creating them in ENVI, and as such ArcMap could not process them. I had to export each as a new file through ArcMap, reopen them, and then use the following syntax:

Con("Raster1" == 3, 1, 0) + Con("Raster2" == 7, 1, 0).....